# Roxygen link to the "[" method

Tags: r, rdoc, roxygen

In my R package, I implemented the `[` (indexing) operator for my class:

```
#' Some title
#' @export
setMethod("[", list(x="MyClass"), function(x, i, j, ...) {
  # Some code
})
```

Now, in the package documentation I want to link to the manual entry for this method. I try the normal way, using `methodName,className-method`:

```
#' [[,MyClass-method]
```

But that just puts a left bracket outside of the `\link` command in the `.Rd` file:

```
[\link{,MyClass-method}
```

If I try to quote it in some way, I get other issues: I have tried backtick, single and double quotes, and finally doubling the bracket `[[` but none of these seem to produce a link that actually works in the final PDF.

How can I cross reference a `[` method using Roxygen?

Comment: I'd try escaping it with a backslash, `#' \[[,Myclass-method]` (or maybe 2)

Comment: If I use the backslash to escape the second bracket ie `[\[,MyClass-method]`, then I get `\item [[,MyClass-method]`. If I escape the first racket `\[[,MyClass-method]` I get `[\link{,HistDat-method}`. Neither is right, though. The correct output would be `\link{[,HistDat-method}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "rd-formatting" vignette in `roxygen2` (which you can see using `vignette("rd-formatting", package = "roxygen2")`):

> Links to operators or objects that contain special characters do not currently work. So to link to (e.g.) the `%>%` operator in the `magrittr` package, instead of `[magrittr::%>%]`, you will need to use the Rd notation: `\code{\link[magrittr]{\%>\%}}`.

This works for documenting `[`, plus other operators, including the "assign" operators/functions that use the "assign" operator, `<-`. For example,

```
\code{\link[myPackage]{[}}
\code{\link[myPackage]{[[}}
\code{\link[myPackage]{$}}
\code{\link[myPackage]{[<-}}
\code{\link[myPackage]{[[<-}}
\code{\link[myPackage]{[levels<-}}
```

all work. If you want to link to the operator of another package, replace `myPackage` with `otherPackage`.

On the same note, the `roxygen2` method of making links like, `[levels<-]` or `[$]` will not work for these kinds of links, or if they do, throw notes/warnings when using `devtools::check()` nonetheless.